# Create a Fixed-Width Text File

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Good evening

I am making an application where I read a file and after processing the data I have a DataFrame with the information and the program output needs to be a Fixed-Width Text File with the data that is in that DataFrame.

The layout would be that way.

In bold are the values ​​that must be replaced, this layout is fixed only changes the values

```
01 DATA DO RECEBIMENTO...... :  **24/01/2011**
01 DATA DO PROCESSAMENTO... :   **27/01/2011**
01 PERIODO DA REMESSA...... :   **17/01/2011 A 23/01/2011**
01 TIPO DE REMESSA......... :   **RN**
01
01
01 A) REGISTROS DE CARROS.................................................................................................     **4.963**
01
01 B) REGISTROS DE MOTOS...............................................................................................        **88**
01
01 C) REGISTROS DE MULTAS.................................................................................................     4.875
01
01 D) TIPOS DE MULTAS...................................................................................................       377
01      A................................       157
01      B................................       199
```

Does anyone know what would be the best way to generate a Fixed-Width Text File using the data in that DataFrame.

I need to generate a file in this layout because I will send this information to the MainFrame

Comment: Hi user72495, it seems you tagged this question with R. Are you hoping to use the R programing language?

Comment: @IanCampbell Oh no sorry. Only scala

Comment: Dataframe does not persist sequence as it is distributed, lines will shuffle in your text file if you wright it from Dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

We can use **`lpad`** or **`rpad`** functions to generate fixed width dataframe and while writing the dataframe to HDFS keep `header` as `false`.

**Example:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.show()
//+---+---+---+
//|  i|  j|  k|
//+---+---+---+
//|  1|  a|  b|
//|  2|  c|  d|
//+---+---+---+

//length of each field
val len_fixed_width= 10

//on all columns doing lpad and then concat all columns at the end
val df2=df.columns.foldLeft(df){ (tempdf, colName) =>
  tempdf.withColumn(colName, lpad(col(s"${colName}"),len_fixed_width," "))
}.selectExpr("concat(*) fixedwidth")

df2.show(false)

//+------------------------------+
//|fixedwidth                    |
//+------------------------------+
//|         1         a         b|
//|         2         c         d|
//+------------------------------+

//for rpad
val df3=df.columns.foldLeft(df){ (tempdf, colName) =>
  tempdf.withColumn(colName, rpad(col(s"${colName}"),len_fixed_width," "))
}.selectExpr("concat(*) fixedwidth")

df3.show(false)
//+------------------------------+
//|fixedwidth                    |
//+------------------------------+
//|1         a         b         |
//|2         c         d         |
//+------------------------------+

//writing to filesystem(HDFS,s3..etc)
df3.write.option("header","false").csv("hdfs_path")
```